# How pass props?

Tags: reactjs

Create the App2.js component and plug it into App.js. Pass s3 as props z1 inside App2. Bring it to a page in App2 as props.

What do when I pass props z1?

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return { z1: props.s3 }
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 2):

you pass in props to App2 using the following

`<App2 z1={this.s3Object} />`

And you would access the prop inside App2, if it's extended `React.Component` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.props.z1 // this z1 object is the one you passed in from App.js.
  //You can access this.props.z1 anywhere inside of your class, not just constructor
}
```

Look here if you're planning on learning ReactJS, https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try using below

```
// App.js
<App2 s3Value={this.state.s3 />
```

Inside the App2.js

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
        z1:props.s3Value
       }
}
```

can use props inside constructor and also inside render() method like below. And can use inside the method also

```
render() {
    var z1= this.props.s3Value;
    ...
}
```